# YOXView doesn't work on iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, yoxview

I used YOXView image gallery on my site, on both desktop and ipad it works perfect, however it doesn't work on my iPhone, when I click on the image, instead of triggering the gallery, it just goes to a new page with the bigger version of the images, does anyone know what's the problem? I've searched everywhere and can not find an answer, thanks! below is the YOXView related code I had in my file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#multiGallery1").yoxview({
                images: [
                    { media: { src: '../img/pf_2.jpg' }},
                    { media: { src: '../img/pf_3.jpg' }}
                ]
            });
        });


        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#multiGallery2").yoxview({
                images: [
                    { media: { src: '../img/pf_6.jpg'}},
                    { media: { src: '../img/pf_7.jpg'}}
                ]
            });
        });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="../img/pf_1.jpg" id="multiGallery1" ><img src="../img/holder_i2.png"/></a> &nbsp;
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, just need different image gallery ID with desktop and ipad.